# Changing angle of map in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-plugins

I have a map of streets and buildings that I need to change their angel on the map. It is also necessary that the name labels will change respectively.
This is a screen shot of the map [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the print composer, select the map then go to its item properties and set a rotation angle.

[image]

As asked in the question, the labels are automatically adjusted. Note that the following screenshot is just using the labels with the default options.
[image]

Comment: Does it change the label rotation so the caption will be in the right angle like in the plugin?

Comment: @NitzanMatan yes, the labels are adjusted. See updated screenshot

Answer (score 1):

I have look into it and find a pretty good solution.
I head installed a plugin that was made for this function "Dockable MirrorMap"[image].
When I click the icon a window is opens [image]
The green "plus" icon is used to add the layers into the function window. [image]
The "rotation" bar is used to specifies in how many degrees the layers will move. In me case 140 [image]